# Selenium- how to automate download in http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I am using selenium to automation the downloading of from a website:

```
http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown
```

There is no problem for me to click 'OK' in the first page, but I cannot click 'Download' in the second page. The error message is 'No such element'

below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

driver=webdriver.Chrome(os.path.expanduser('./chromedriver'))
driver.get('http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="node-36"]/div/div/div/div/form/p[1]/select/option[190]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="node-36"]/div/div/div/div/form/p[3]/input').click()


# this is the one has problem
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="node-39"]/div/div/div/div/a/h2').click()
```

I tried find_element_by_xpath, find_element_by_class_name ... none of them work. Could anyone familiar with Selenium help me solving this problem?

Comment: Share your html element

Comment: ... and share the actual selenium code and xpath or class name that you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I have added my codes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Update

Whether link is not comply HTML, but selenium manage to find link itself.

So like answer above, what you have to do is wait just more seconds.

### Another solution: Using Requests only

> It is not about `selenium` but this solution can make your crawler much more faster than `selenium`.

Site's problem is link(download link) is NOT comply HTML.

Because it's link is like this:

```
<a href=http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/KOR_adm.zip>
<h2>Download</h2></a>
```

It should be like this:

```
<a href="http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/KOR_adm.zip">
<h2>Download</h2></a>
```

So selenium couldn't find  tag element correctly. neither BeautifulSoup so.

So I use `re` for finding link....

Try with this code:

```
import re
import requests

cookies = {
    'has_js': '1',
}

headers = {
    'Origin': 'http://www.diva-gis.org',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,la;q=0.2,da;q=0.2',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Referer': 'http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1',
}

data = [
    ('cnt', 'AFG_Afghanistan'),
    ('thm', 'adm#Administrative areas (GADM)'),
    ('OK', 'OK'),
    ('_submit_check', '1'),
]

r = requests.post('http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
pattern = re.compile('href=.+zip')
zip_link = pattern.findall(r.text)[0].replace("href=", '').replace("'", '')

print(zip_link)

filename = re.findall("[^/]*$", zip_link)[0]
response = requests.get(zip_link, stream=True)
f = open(filename, "wb+")
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:
        f.write(chunk)
```

This Code will do with no selenium but pretend like Chrome, POST request so that you can get informations.

What you have to do is change data var.

Comment: I think your initial statement is false. I was able to find the Download link just fine using selenium.

Comment: Okay, so your code is working, then why don't you use it?
You can find url (it means you can find a tag) then why don't you click it?
Why do to click h2 tag? How about click a tag instead?

Comment: There's no need to click on the H1 element. You need to click on the anchor element.

Comment: And one more thing, my initial statement is True. If you are looking chrome's element tab, surely you can get it corrected with Chrome itself. But it you're look real HTTP Response then you'll see the response HTML is broken.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more explicit. The statement "So selenium couldn't find tag element correctly." is false, since selenium can indeed find it.

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with being able to find the element or not, the problem is that the OP isn't waiting for the page to be rendered before looking for the link.

Comment: Thank you all! It is helpful

Comment: @Robin1988 How about try with `requests` instead `selenium`? This solution will make your process much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the button just a millisecond or two after clicking the "Ok" button, without giving the page a chance to render. You need to wait for the page to refresh before you can search for the Download button.

For example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

...

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Download")))
    element.click()
except:
    print("unable to find the Download button after 10 seconds")
```

---

Here is a complete working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown")
form = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("form")
form.submit()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Download")))
    element.click()
except:
    print("unable to find the Download button after 10 seconds")

driver.close()
```

Comment: @Robin1988: "not working" is not very useful. I was able to successfully download the file with the exact code above (plus the missing bits that opened the driver and submitted the form).

Comment: It's a little weird, I increase the time of WebDriverWait, and also use time.sleep() to increase the time to load the page, but I still can only get 'unable to find the Download button after 10 seconds'

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. It still print '"unable to find the Download button after 10 seconds". May I ask what's the version of Chrome and chromedriver that you are using?

Comment: @Robin1988: I have chromedriver 2.32, chrome version 60.0.3112.101. The code I posted also worked with firefox (except that it popped up a dialog rather than downloading the file).

Comment: it turns out a version problem. I was using chrome 48 in ubuntu 15.04. Now I installed 16.04 and use chrome 61, even my original code works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well. I neither did use selenium nor regex to accomplish the task. Upon execution you will have your desired zip file downloaded according to your selected folder.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

base_link = "http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown"

def download_file(link):
    payload = {'cnt':'AFG_Afghanistan','thm':'adm#Administrative areas (GADM)','OK':'OK','_submit_check':'1'}

    headers={
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    page = requests.post(link, data=payload, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".field-item a"):
        zipresp = urlopen(item['href'])
        tempzip = open(r"C:\Users\ar\Desktop\mth.zip", "wb")  #change the address according to your need
        tempzip.write(zipresp.read())
        tempzip.close()

download_file(base_link)
```

Answer (score -1):

What error you are getting? Check if there is any frame. If any frame then you need to switch to frame first

Comment: Right click on your element. If you can see 'view this frame' option that means your element is within frame. Then You need to switch to that particular frame by driver.switchTo.frame("frame name ") method and locate element